# How to minimize jquery.mmenu.all.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, minify, mmenu

I notice that mmenu doesn't provide minimized versions of their files.
I'm not sure what the safest way to do so is.
I want to minify jquery.mmenu.all.js and jquery.mmenu.all.css
if it makes a difference I have phpstorm and netbeans

Comment: Try https://www.minifier.org/

Comment: Thanks, there are so many and I don't know which to trust.  I wonder why mmenu doesn't offer pre-minified files.

Comment: How do you mean "trust", exactly? All minification does is shrink the variable names and compress the spacing, generally. The code is public anyway so you're not giving anyone some IP. If these tools resulted in broken code, people wouldn't use them. The one I mentioned above has a very short issues log: https://github.com/matthiasmullie/minify/issues.

Comment: TBH though, looking at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FrDH/jQuery.mmenu/master/dist/jquery.mmenu.all.js, it's actually quite minified already, you won't be able to compress it a huge amount more. Just cos they didn't name it `.min.js` doesn't mean it hasn't undergone some compression during the build process. Same with https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FrDH/jQuery.mmenu/master/dist/jquery.mmenu.all.css . According to https://github.com/FrDH/jQuery.mmenu/blob/master/README.md they use Gulp to "transpile, minify and concatenate the TS/JS and SCSS/CSS files".

Comment: Since the plugin is written in TypeScript (for the code) and SCSS (for the CSS), there is in fact no direct equivalent raw "un-minified" version of the JS file - what you get in  jquery.mmenu.all.js is the result of compiling and compressing the TypeScript via the Gulp tool. If you look in the "src" folder on Github you won't see a direct source JS file for it, instead there are lots of TypeScript files which make up the solution.